# Is it possible to make a NSTable view "wrap" cells into new colums?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a standard single column `NSTableView` that has a setup like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Is it possible to make the data display horizontally and then wrap like this?

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Or should I not be using an NSTableView entirely? I was trying to avoid using extensive logic to do this.

Comment: You mean like a collection view does?

Comment: There's no "extensive logic" in mapping a linear array to a 2D table: dividing by the number of columns gives you a row; obtaining a remainder gives you the column. Reverse mapping is `index=row*columnCount+column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this but directly there is no such api to make it horizontally. You have to take three columns then insert first row of data into three columns. After 3 columns data has been inserted then you have to start filling on the next rows like that logic you can implement on your table view. Also how you can achieve the same is take one array add the above number 1-9 in your array then run the loop inside that take mutable dictionary for every 3 values start putting your data into your rows once three has been inserted start filling the same onto the next rows.
Below is the small code, and bindings which you need to do:-

```
        1)Drag and drop arraycontroller 
        now go to binding inspector and see the binding in the screen shot attached:-
        ![enter image description here][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcDy.png

2) Now in your table view select first column and do the binding in attached screen shot
![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]


3) similarly do for second and third column with name inside model key path for second column give name second and for third column give third.

4) Once binding has done.
Write the below code in your method where you required:

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    int i,j=1,k=2,l=3;
    self.yourArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (i=0; i<3;i++)
        {        
        NSMutableDictionary *dc=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j] forKey:@"first"];
        [dc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:k] forKey:@"second"];
        [dc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:l] forKey:@"third"];
        [self.yourArray addObject:dc];
        [self setYourArray:self.yourArray];
        j=j+3;
        k=k+3;
        l=l+3;
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cm6M.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cm6M.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51oET.png
```

Comment: How can I make a for loop like that? I start with an array of data.

Comment: Can you please tell me?